# how to create inner object in object (stdClass) using Laravel to remove duplicate values

Tags: php, laravel-8

my query in the controller
i have tree table and i joined it with the help of join method

```
$attendance = DB::table('attendances')
        ->join('users', 'attendances.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('subjects', 'attendances.subject_id', '=', 'subjects.id')
        ->where('attendances.subject_id', '=',$ideas[0])
        ->whereBetween('attendances.date',array($dateFrom, $dateTo))
        ->join('class_studs', 'attendances.class_stud_id', '=', 'class_studs.id')
        ->select('attendances.status','attendances.date','attendances.leave','users.firstname','users.admissionNo','subjects.name', 'class_studs.semester','class_studs.department','class_studs.session')
        ->get();
```

and the output of this

```
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => P
        [date] => 10/02/2022
        [leave] => 
        [firstname] => testing
        [admissionNo] => 0059
        [name] => Data Science
        [semester] => 6th
        [department] => computer Science
        [session] => 2019-2023
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => P
        [date] => 10/02/2022
        [leave] => 
        [firstname] => arsalan
        [admissionNo] => 0056
        [name] => Data Science
        [semester] => 6th
        [department] => computer Science
        [session] => 2019-2023
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => P
        [date] => 10/02/2022
        [leave] => 
        [firstname] => khan
        [admissionNo] => 004
        [name] => Data Science
        [semester] => 6th
        [department] => computer Science
        [session] => 2019-2023
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => P
        [date] => 10/03/2022
        [leave] => 
        [firstname] => testing
        [admissionNo] => 0059
        [name] => Data Science
        [semester] => 6th
        [department] => computer Science
        [session] => 2019-2023
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => L
        [date] => 10/03/2022
        [leave] => L
        [firstname] => arsalan
        [admissionNo] => 0056
        [name] => Data Science
        [semester] => 6th
        [department] => computer Science
        [session] => 2019-2023
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => A
        [date] => 10/03/2022
        [leave] => 
        [firstname] => khan
        [admissionNo] => 004
        [name] => Data Science
        [semester] => 6th
        [department] => computer Science
        [session] => 2019-2023
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => P
        [date] => 10/04/2022
        [leave] => 
        [firstname] => testing
        [admissionNo] => 0059
        [name] => Data Science
        [semester] => 6th
        [department] => computer Science
        [session] => 2019-2023
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => P
        [date] => 10/04/2022
        [leave] => 
        [firstname] => arsalan
        [admissionNo] => 0056
        [name] => Data Science
        [semester] => 6th
        [department] => computer Science
        [session] => 2019-2023
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => P
        [date] => 10/04/2022
        [leave] => 
        [firstname] => khan
        [admissionNo] => 004
        [name] => Data Science
        [semester] => 6th
        [department] => computer Science
        [session] => 2019-2023
    )
```

I want to remove the duplicate values
because there are three records in the database table but in the front end 9 records show duplicated, please help me.
my tried methods
->toString()
array_unique()
but no result

Comment: You cannot be using laravel 8 and 9? Please use the tags carefully so you gather the correct audience for your question, thats what they are for

Comment: Can you try a LeftJoin

Comment: same result on leftjoin

Comment: sorry sir I am using laravel-8

Answer (score 0):

The easiest but stupid way is using group_by on unique column
Here it is admissionNo I think
So just add ->groupBy(“admissionNo”)

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'jca.attendances.status' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by